# Best Practices for plugin development

Tags: plugin-development

The plugin docs are a good reference but can be a bit daunting when piecing things together, any good plugins from the community that are well commented/built etc. ? Especially in regard to elements.

Comment: It doesn't include elements, but I did write a [plugin template...](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-businesslogic)

Comment: here's a good one for getting into elements  https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Events

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mijingo has a great video on plugin development at https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/craft-plugin-development/

Outside of that I'd take a look at the plugins at https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/